# Access notification log data

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I wanted to know how can I access the data which comes with our notification in notification log. Like I just want to know which app sent the notification, if the user opened that notification or not and when the notification arrived. I want to use these data in my app to process these data items and display it on my android app.
Please help.

Comment: Hi @Manas, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No :( @CliffBurton